# Summation of indices with same element in an array in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have two lists `Ii01` and `Iv01`. `Ii01` consists of a numpy array with indices. `Iv01` consists of values corresponding to these indices. For example, `[2.1]` in `Iv01` corresponds to `[3,1]` in `Ii01`.

I want to sum indices with the same `j`. For example, values corresponding  to `[0, 3],[2, 3],[4, 3]` in `Iv01` are to be summed since there are 3 elements with `j=3`. Similarly, values corresponding  to `[0, 4],[2, 4]` in `Iv01` are to be summed since there are 2 elements with `j=4`. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
Ii01 = [np.array([[3, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 3],
       [0, 4],
       [2, 4]])]

Iv01 = [np.array([[2.1],
       [3.4],
       [1.5],
       [9.7],
       [6.5],
       [4.2],
       [1.7]])]
```

The expected output is

```
[np.array([[2.1],
       [3.4],
       [1.5+9.7+6.5],
       [4.2+1.7]])]
```

Comment: What do you mean by * summed and divided by 3*? `[0, 3]+[2, 3]+[4, 3]` will result in a list containing all the values, you can't divide it by int.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to just sum the similar indices? I have modified the post.

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, `+` between lists merge the lists, it doesn't sum them. It's still not clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use a property of least squares, although it might seem a little cryptic.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[3, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [2, 3], [4, 3], [0, 4], [2, 4]])

uniq = np.unique(a[:, 1][None, :])

y = a[:, 0]
x = a[:, 1][:, None] == uniq

output = np.vstack((np.linalg.lstsq(x, y, rcond=None)[0], uniq)).T

print(output)
# [[3. 1.]
#  [0. 2.]
#  [2. 3.]
#  [1. 4.]]
```

Another option is not to use `numpy` but to use `itertools.groupby`. This assumes that the same group is formd by *adjacent* rows sharing the second element.

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def mean(xs):
    return sum(xs) / len(xs)

output = [[mean([x[0] for x in g]), k] for k, g in groupby(a, key=itemgetter(1))]

print(output) # [[3.0, 1], [0.0, 2], [2.0, 3], [1.0, 4]]
```

By the way, note that `Ii01` is a singleton *list* of an array. In the above pieces of code, I assumed you are dealing with just one array, i.e., `a = Ii01[0]`.

Comment: I modified my post to highlight better what I am trying to implement.